# How to restrict access to JMX API of ActiveMQ to only localhost/intranet?

Tags: jmx, activemq-classic

I have just started using JMX to monitor activemq,i have enabled remote monitoring. Now the question is,How do i allow only localhost have access to JMX API? Or is there a way i can use JMX API without enabling remote monitoring..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After spending hours of my time googling for a solution, i came across this article https://wiki.internet2.edu/confluence/display/CPD/Monitoring+Tomcat+with+JMX which shows how to configure JMX for tomcat and how to expose JMX over rmi. 
The option "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=test-idc.internet2.edu" indicates the name of the host on which tomcat is running. If you donot specify the hostname then trying to connect from a remote machine returns 'Connection failed'.

All you need to do is to set the property -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost in your activemq startup script

```
if [ -z "$SUNJMX" ] ; then
  #SUNJMX="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
  SUNJMX="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
fi
```

Thats it... restart activemq and you have jmx accessible only from your local machine.